# Couldn't find "fullcalendar"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We're using [Rails Assets](https://rails-assets.org/) in our project and we're in the process of updating Ruby from `2.3.7` to `2.4.7`, following [this guide](https://everydayrails.com/2017/12/18/ruby-upgrade-guide-for-rails.html). I think I've resolved all the gems issues, but when I'm trying to run `rspec` or navigate to any admin page, I'm greeted with this error:

```
couldn't find file 'fullcalendar'
```

This is one of the `Rails Assets` mentioned above, and I'm not sure why this is happening.

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-jquery'
  gem 'rails-assets-jquery-ujs'
  gem 'rails-assets-jquery-ui'
  gem 'rails-assets-js-cookie'
  gem 'rails-assets-lodash'
  gem 'rails-assets-highcharts'
  # gem 'rails-assets-quill'
  gem 'rails-assets-select2'
  gem 'rails-assets-select2-bootstrap-css'
  gem 'rails-assets-slick.js'
  gem 'rails-assets-picturefill'
  gem 'rails-assets-scrollmagic'
  gem 'rails-assets-gsap'
  gem 'rails-assets-fullcalendar'
  gem 'rails-assets-moment'
  gem 'rails-assets-jstzdetect'
  gem 'rails-assets-blueimp-file-upload'
  gem 'rails-assets-air-datepicker'
end
```

/app/views/layouts/admin.haml:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'admin'
```

/app/assets/javascripts/admin.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ujs
//= require jquery-ui/jquery-ui
//= require lodash
//= require bootstrap
//= require moment
//= require quill
//= require fullcalendar
//= require select2
//= require jstzdetect
//= require cocoon
//= require blueimp-file-upload/jquery.iframe-transport.js
//= require blueimp-file-upload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js
//= require blueimp-file-upload/jquery.fileupload.js
//= require_tree ./admin
```

What have me scratching my head is that the assets above `fullcalendar` are loading fine, but this one throws an error.

This app is running on `Rails 4.2.7.1` and `ruby 2.3.7`. I'm trying to update Ruby version to `ruby 2.4.7`.

Comment: Did you first try to run `bin/rake 'component:convert[fullcalendar,3.10.0]'` then`bundle` ? Or whatever version you're using?

Comment: I tried that but I got this error: `Don't know how to build task 'component:convert'`. I checked out the README on https://github.com/tenex/rails-assets and it seems that command only applies to the development aspect of the gem, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `require fullcalendar` with

```
require fullcalendar/core/main.js
require fullcalendar/daygrid/main.js
```

Just a guess based on [the doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals)

Alternatively, just remove it from assets and put the files directly in vendor folder; or use [this gem](https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails).

Comment: The first suggestion didn't work, I was still greeted with the same error. However, removing it from my assets and use the `fullcalendar-rails` gem instead worked!

I still wonder why I was getting that error when it was fine when the app was running on ruby 2.3.7. I guess it doesn't matter anymore, but it'd still be nice to know :D